# Join (meet) homomorphisms implying order-homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

> Every join-(or meet-) homomorphism is an order-homomorphism.

$f$ is a join-homomorphism $\implies f(x\vee y)=f(x)\vee f(y)$. To show that $f$ is order-homomorphism, I need to show $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$.

Now $x\le y\implies x\wedge y=x$. I now cannot use $f(x\wedge y)=f(x)$ because $f$ is not injective here. I'm stuck here to move from domain to codomain.

Also if I jump from domain to codomain, how do I convert    $f(x\wedge y)$ to $f(x\vee y)$.
I'm not getting a way to sort this out.

Same thing happens with meet-homomorphism.

**P.S: If any one of the proofs is done, then the other can be done using duality. But I want to prove them separately.**

Comment: Did you mean to use joins in your middle paragraph?

Comment: yes. I'm not getting how to jump from domain to codomain simply because $f$ is not injective here. So i can't use $x\wedge y=x\implies f(x\wedge y)=f(x)$ and same for $\vee$.

Comment: and also how to convert $\wedge$ to $\vee$ and vice-versa

Comment: Please edit your question if a typo is pointed out to you.

Comment: @CaptainLama there is no typo. jackozee meant whether I'm interested to know how I insert $\vee$ in place of $\wedge$ in my calculation.

Comment: Ok. Notice that $a=b$ always implies $f(a)=f(b)$ for any function $f$, it juste mean the function iswell-defined. Injectivity gives the converse implication.

Comment: Then $x\wedge y=x\implies f(x\wedge y)=f(x)=f(x)\wedge f(y)$ is done for meet part. But I am also not able to change $\vee$ for join part of the proof.

Comment: In a lattice $a\le b\iff a\lor b=b\iff a\land b=a$.

Comment: Thanks @Berci..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a join homomorphism $f:A\to B$.
Suppose $x,y\in A$ are elements with $x\leq y$, which is equivalent to $x\vee y=y$. Since $f$ is a function, you have $f(x\vee y)=f(y)$, but this is the same as $f(x)\vee f(y)=f(y)$, which is equivalent to $f(x)\leq f(y)$.

Now can you do the same with $\wedge$?

Comment: I did the meet part in one of the above comments. And I wanted to do the join part using $x\wedge y=x$ rather than $x\vee y=y$. However, thanks for you help. This is also a nice suggestion.

Comment: Do not accept an answer if you don't think it actually answers your question. Someone might have an answer, but won't even read your question since it has been marked as answered.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Let me see if I understood right.
Do you want to prove that a join homomorphism $f:A\to B$ is an order homomorphism using the equivalence $x\wedge y=y \iff y\leq x$?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz yes you're right. Since I've just started the lessons of lattices, I would like to keep all notations same as used most. So a little more change in your proposition. $x\le y\iff x\wedge y=x$.

Comment: @CaptainLama I'm aware of that fact. But this answer also satisfied my queries. that's why I accepted this. Moreover, I didn't think of taking join for defining the order relation. So i liked it. +1 for your suggestion though.